# Using bash to find absolute path to specific directory

Tags: bash

I've been trying to write a simple bash script to enter into a couple of directories and install all RPMs in those directories. However, I am having difficulty getting the absolute path for the directories. Right now I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd readlink -f my_dir;
mvn clean install;
sudo rpm -U $(find . -type f -name \*.rpm);
```

The code for the other directories is exactly the same save for the directory name. The issue I am having is `cd readlink -f my_dir;` attempts to change the directory to `absolute/path/to/cur_dir/my_dir`; it tacks on the name of the directory at the end. How do I solve this issue?

**Clarification**

I am trying to get the absolute path to a directory regardless of my current position in the file system. What I am getting now is the absolute path to my current directory with the name of the desired directory appended to it.

Answer (score 3):

`cd readlink -f my_dir` should be `cd $(readlink -f my_dir)`.

Comment: I tried that, but it is still getting the absolute path to my current directory instead of `my_dir`

Comment: What do you get if you run `readlink -f my_dir` in your terminal?